# How to retrieve csrf token generated with flask in vue js frontend

Tags: vue.js, flask, axios, flask-wtforms, csrf-token

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using Flask for the backend and Vue.js for the frontend. I've successfully generated a CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) token in Flask using {{ form.hidden_tag() }} within my templates, which works well. However, I'm facing a challenge when it comes to integrating Vue.js into the mix.

I'd like to know how to generate and utilize a CSRF token with Vue.js in my Flask application. The problem lies in replicating the same CSRF token handling mechanism within Vue.js as I do with Flask templates.

To give you a clearer picture, here's a snippet of my current setup:

```
@app.route("/api/register", methods=['GET','POST'])
    def register():
        data = request.json  # Parse JSON data from the Vue.js frontend
        print(data)
        # Validate and process the registration data
        form = RegistrationForm(**data)
        print(form.username.data)
        if form.validate():
            user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data)
            user.set_password(form.password1.data)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
        return jsonify(success=True, message='Registration successful')

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[
        DataRequired(),
        Length(min=4, max=20),
        Regexp(r'^\w+$', message="Username must contain only letters, numbers, or underscores.")
    ])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password1 = PasswordField('Password', validators=[
        DataRequired(),
        Length(min=8),
        Regexp(r'^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]+$',
               message="Password must include at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one digit, and one special character.")
    ])
    password2 = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[
        DataRequired(),
        EqualTo('password1', message='Passwords must match.')
    ])
    submit = SubmitField('Register')
    
        # sanitization to the username and email fields
    def validate_username(self, field):
        field.data = bleach.clean(field.data)

    def validate_email(self, field):
        field.data = bleach.clean(field.data)
```

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3>Create a new Account!</h3>
    <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
           
      <div>
        <label for="username">Username :</label>
        <input v-model="formData.username" placeholder="username" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="email">Email :</label>
        <input v-model="formData.email" placeholder="email" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="password">Password :</label>
        <input v-model="formData.password" placeholder="password" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="password2">Confirm :</label>
        <input v-model="formData.confirm" placeholder="confirm" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div v-if="errors.length > 0">
      <p v-for="error in errors" :key="error">{{ error }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      formData: {
        username: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        confirm: "",
      },
      errors: []
    };
  },
  
  
  methods: {
    async handleSubmit() {
      try {
        // Perform validation here (e.g., check if passwords match, etc.)
        if (this.formData.password !== this.formData.confirm) {
          this.errors = ["Passwords do not match"];
          return;
        }

        // Send the registration data to the server with the CSRF token in the header
        const response = await axios.post(
          "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/register",
          this.formData,
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          }
        );

        if (response.data.success) {
          // Registration was successful, perform any necessary actions
          // (e.g., redirect to login page)
          this.$router.push({ name: "login" });
        } else {
          // Handle registration failure
          this.errors = [response.data.message];
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle network or server errors
        console.error(error);
        this.errors = [
          "An error occurred while processing your request. Please try again later.",
        ];
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

However, despite trying different approaches, I haven't been able to successfully use this CSRF token when making AJAX requests from Vue.js to my Flask backend. How can I include the CSRF token in the request headers when using Axios or any other method in Vue.js?

Your guidance on how to handle CSRF tokens between Flask and Vue.js would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First Generate and pass the CSRF token to Vue on initial render. Store it in Vue and add to request headers and validate the token in Flask on each request.

**Example**

1. In Flask, generate the CSRF token and pass it to the initial page render:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
  csrf_token = generate_csrf()

  return render_template('index.html', csrf_token=csrf_token)
```

2. In Vue, store the CSRF token in a data property:

```
data() {
  return {
    csrfToken: '' 
  }
}

created() {
  this.csrfToken = // Get from rendered page 
}
```

3. Add the CSRF token to the Axios request headers:

```
axios.post('/api/register', data, {
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': this.csrfToken
  }  
})
```

4. In Flask, validate the CSRF token on requests:

```
@app.route('/api/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
  csrf_token = request.headers.get('X-CSRF-TOKEN')
  if not validate_csrf(csrf_token):
    abort(400)

  // process request
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer with this approach , please can you explain a little bit more about step 1 and 2